# Opera Mini link outline issue

Tags: html, css, click, focus, opera-mini

I am clicking on 1 image but other images showing it has been focused on opera mini. I want while cliking it will just focus on corresponding image.

[image]

This is my html

[image]

Any idea? TIA

Comment: Add your code, not screenshots of it. Your question should be reproducible by others, and they don't want to retype it to reproduce it.

Comment: I have found it. Reason is. All are the same link. That's why showing it.

Answer (score 0):

Opera Mini outline all links on page that are goint to the same page.

This is just Opera Mini behavior (may be for saving your browse time on site)